# Django not found in Eclipse IDE on Windows

Tags: python, windows, django, eclipse

I'm trying to create a Django project in Eclipse but it says I have no Django installed, Although I've run a script which imports django and print its version and everything works fine, but in Eclipse not.

[image: The script I've run in Eclipse]

See that it prints Django version correctly and every module I have. Now see what Eclipse says:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove then re-add the python interpreter.